# Redis OM using Python - Index not found

Tags: redis

I am using JsonModel class with redis OM to save records in Redis. I have two applications.

Application One - It is a standalone Python Application. It saves the records in Redis with Index on the id column . It also able find a record in Redis by id.

Second APplication - It is a FastAPI application with a get method. It is finding the record by id but it throws the error - redis.exceptions.ResponseError: :main.Product:index: no such index

### My observation:

```
**The keys in redis are stored as follows:
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) ":__main__.Product:01H1RHTS1X321AE7822S0RPYPX"
2) ":__main__.Product:01H1RHTS1XWWSXBWQB1PCJA23P"
3) ":__main__.Product:01H1RHTS1X1666X639Y8W72KF8"
4) ":__main__.Product:index:hash"**
```

However the second app - Fast API looks for main.Product:index.

Appreciate if any one can help in how to resolve this issue.